# Notification at certain time using a Service

Tags: java, android-service

I am developing an Android prayer app for Muslims. I have already developed the code to obtain the prayer times with the help of [praytimes.org](http://praytimes.org). Now I want to make it so that the user is notified at that time to pray. But for now, I just want to be able to send a notification at a certain time. Looking at the code and online resources, it seems to me as if it should work but for some reason, the notification is not displaying. I know the code for the notification part is correct because I created a button to create a notification using that code and it works. So I believe the problem is with the service, receiver, or alarmManager.

My guess is the problem has to do with the onStartCommand() method in MyNotificationService.java. I am not too familiar with services and their life-cycles so please go easy on me.

Thanks in advance.

In my MainActivity.java, here is the code in my onCreate() method.

```
/*========================Begin Notification Code==============================*/

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 18);

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

/*========================End Notification Code==============================*/
```

Here is MyReceiver.class

```
package com.ahmed.omar.tawheed;

/**
 * Created by Omar on 1/18/15.
 */
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, MyNotificationService.class);    
        context.startService(service);

    }
}
```

Here is MyNotificationService.java

```
package com.ahmed.omar.tawheed;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;


public class MyNotificationService extends Service  {

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private int prayerNotificationID = 420; //blazeIt

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        super.onCreate();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent1, int flag, int startId) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Notification n  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Time to Pray")
                .setContentText("It is now time to pray salah")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Sending the notification itself
        notificationManager.notify(prayerNotificationID, n);

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Here are the lines from my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".MyNotificationService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"/>
```

Comment: I haven't looked at your code carefully, but generally speaking I prefer to implement long timing services like this with [Crontab.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)  It's robust and well understood and well suited to servers.  Anything else tends to be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @markspace Considering that I'm very new to android development, you suggest that I should use Crontab rather than just a service to notify users of prayer times everyday? This is just a clarification of your comment.

Comment: Oh, I thought this was a server service, not something running entirely on a mobile device.  Sorry about that, I don't know if `cron` runs on an Android.

Comment: @markspace I've edited my question to include Android app. Do you know of an answer to why the notification is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [Calendar.MONTH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH). The valid values start at 0 (for January), not 1. So, your code is trying to set an alarm on February 18, not January 18. Try changing the Calendar.MONTH value to 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Good catch. But changing the month to 0 and changing the hour_of_day (which is 24 hour) to 20 (the local time here) I still didn't get any luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do for send notification.

```
  fun showNotification(context: Context,title: String, message: String) {
    Log.e("notification", "visible")
    val mNotificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel("1",
            "NAMAJ_CHANNEL",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        channel.description = "namaj alarm channel"
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "1")
        .setSmallIcon(com.waltonbd.muslimcalender.R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon
        .setContentTitle(title) // title for notification
        .setContentText(message)// message for notification
        .setAutoCancel(true) // clear notification after click
    val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi)
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build())
}
```